# How to read from multiple cells in Excel using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I wanted to add Windows Forms controls to an excel document I created.

To do so, I created a new project using the Office 2010 Excel 2010 Workbook template in VS 2010 (C#). All I am trying to do is copy data from multiple cells and write them to a text file.

Whenever I put all of the cells I want under a single Name Space, and then try to read the "Value2", I just get "System.Object[,]".

All I have done so far is added a radioButton to Sheet 1 and created an event handler. Past that I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Value2` property of a range comes back as a 2-d array of values.  To access the values just loop through the array:

```
object[,] values = range.Values2;
for(int i = 0; i < values.Length(0); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < values.Length(1); j++)
    {
        object cellValue = values[i,j];
        // do something with the value
    }
```

Comment: @D Stanley When I use this code, I get syntax errors stating "cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[*,*]'". Also I'm dealing with just numbers. I'm copying hex-decimal values from the cells so I'm not sure if cycling through will just work.

Comment: You'll need to cast to a `double[,]` and may be able to cast the cell values to doubles.  The code I gave is a rough guideline - you'l need to adapt it to meet your specific needs.